# DDD: aggregate root and references to child entities

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, performance, aggregate

I'm struggling a bit to grasp all DDD concepts and apply them to a real project.
Let's say I have the following domain concepts:

- **Car**: a vehicle moving inside an area
- **Path**: a journey made by a car, from A to B. Each car can have many recorded paths, but only an active one at a given moment
- **Position**: the GPS position of a car in a journey, so one path is a collection of positions taken every x seconds
- **Camera**: a video device recording the car during its path, so a position can have a collection of photos recording the car

From that domain I can model the following class hierarchy:

```
Car

    - plate: String
    - paths: Path[]

Path

    - startDate: DateTime
    - positions: Position[]

Position

    - coordinate: LatLng
    - photos: Photo[]    

Photo

    - data: Blob
    - cameraId: Int

Camera

    - serialNumber: String
```

It seems obvious to me that the only entities that can exist on their own are the car and the camera. Photos are collected for each position, positions are collected into a path, and paths exist only as long as their car do.

So I identified one root aggregate, and that's the Car. Now, when a GPS position is recorded, I ask the car to create or return the active path.

```
Path activePath = car.getOrCreateActivePath();
Position lastPosition = activePath.addPosition(coordinate); 
Photo photo = lastPosition.AddPhoto(data);
```

Usually I would have stored that activePath reference and used it to further manipulate the tree, but I've read that aggregate internals should never be accessed from the outside.

So I'd do something like that:

```
car.getOrCreateActivePath();
car.addPositionToActivePath(coordinate);
car.addPhotoToLastPositionOfActivePath(data);
```

This seems like a stretch, and I don't like it at all. I don't even know if it's correct from a DDD point of view. How can I improve that design?

Another related doubt is: let's imagine that a single car can record a hundred paths per day, and it runs until it's broken, so more or less 20 years. Each path is made by hundreds of positions, and every position contains ten photos. Towards the end of its life, a single Car aggregate could load nearly a million paths just to update the position of the last one, and that's without counting all other related entities. This seems to me like a waste of resources, and a potential performance issue. How does DDD cope with problems like that?

Comment: you cant do DDD without business rules.

Comment: Hi Ewan, can you please expand your comment?

Comment: unless you put in all the business rule requirements around these cars and stuff you can't tell if you have chosen the right domain objects or what the AR is. Or tell if your choice is correct